# Trace thought of as a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form over $End_{\Bbb{R}}V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, trace, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a real finite-dimensional vector space of dimension $n$. Let $End_{\Bbb{R}}V$ be the real vector space of linear mappings from $V$ to $V$. $End_{\Bbb{R}}V$ has dimension $n^2$.

The trace is the unique (up to scale) $Tr\in(End_{\Bbb{R}}V)^{*}$ such that $Tr(A\circ B)=Tr(B\circ A)$ for every $A,B\in End_{\Bbb{R}}V$. Normally we take the one that verifies $Tr(Id)=n$, where $Id$ is the identity endomorphism of $V$. This defines a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form: $B_{Tr}:End_{\Bbb{R}}V\times End_{\Bbb{R}}V\to \Bbb{R}$, $B_{Tr}(A,B):=Tr(A\circ B)$.

It is a well known result that non-degenerate symmetric bilinear forms over a real finite-dimensional vector space are classified by the index and the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature), so I wonder:

1. Is there a formula to calculate the index and the signture of $B_{Tr}$ (maybe in terms of the dimension)? In other words, how do I find the corresponding $\pm1s$? There are $n^2$ of them.
2. Who is an orthonormal basis for $(End_{\Bbb{R}}V,B_{Tr})$? In order to solve this, does it help the fact that the orthogonal complement of the symmetric endomorphisms are the alternating ones and viceversa?

For the answerers: I have no knowledge about algebraic geometry. If you are able to connect your answer with ideas of the field of differential geometry it will be appreciated (I'm teaching myself it and that's how I came up with this question). Though coordinates help to understand things, finish with free-coordinate arguments will be appreciated too. Still any help will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user953376 Where did that transpose come from?  We have $B_{\operatorname{Tr}}(A,A)=\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)$ not $\operatorname{Tr}(A^tA)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you choose some inner product $g$ on $V$, you have the notion of an an adjoint map. The bilinear form
$$ B_{g}(T,S) = \operatorname{tr} \left( T^{*} \circ S \right) $$
depends on $g$ (via the adjoint) and defines an inner product (i.e a non-degenerate symmetric positive definite bilinear form) on $\operatorname{End}(V)$ which is sometimes called the "standard" inner product on $\operatorname{End}(V)$ and is commonly used in differential geometry. Now, any operator $T \colon V \rightarrow V$ can be decomposed uniquely as $T = T_1 + T_2$ where $T_1$ is self-adjoint ($T_1^{*} = T_1$) and $T_2$ is skew-adjoint $(T_2^{*} = -T_2$). Explicitly, we have
$$ T = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \left( T + T^{*} \right)}_{T_1} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \left( T - T^{*} \right)}_{T_2}. $$
Hence $\operatorname{End}(V) = \operatorname{End}_{\textrm{self}}(V) \oplus \operatorname{End}_{\textrm{skew}}(V)$. Note that if $T_1 \in \operatorname{End}_{\textrm{self}}(V), T_2 \in \operatorname{End}_{\textrm{skew}}(V)$, we have
$$ B_{\operatorname{tr}} \left( T_1, T_2 \right) = \operatorname{tr} \left( T_1 \circ T_2 \right) = \operatorname{tr} \left( \left( T_1 \circ T_2 \right)^{*} \right) = -\operatorname{tr} \left( T_2 \circ T_1 \right) = -\operatorname{tr} \left( T_1 \circ T_2 \right) = -B_{\operatorname{tr}} \left( T_1, T_2 \right) \implies \\
B_{\operatorname{tr}} (T_1,T_2) = 0.$$
This shows that the decomposition of $\operatorname{End}(V)$ is $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$-orthogonal so it is enough to compute the signature of $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ restricted to each of the subspaces. Note that
$$ B_{\operatorname{tr}}|_{\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{self}}(V)} = B_g|_{\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{self}}(V)}, \qquad B_{\operatorname{tr}}|_{\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{skew}}(V)} = -B_g|_{\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{skew}}(V)} $$
so $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ is positive definite on $\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{self}}(V)$ and negative definite on $\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{skew}}(V)$ which shows that the index of $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ is $\left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \right)$.

---

This calculation of the signature of $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ works by choosing an "auxiliary" inner product $g$ on $V$ and then comparing $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ with $B_g$. By choosing different inner products, you get different forms $B_g$ and different direct sum decompositions of $\operatorname{End}(V)$ but the final result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very interesting, but I have to say two things about it: 1 - You say that you've calculated the signature of $B_{Tr}$, but I think you've calculated the signature of $B_{g}$.  2 - In fact $B_{Tr}$ is a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form by itself, you shouldn't need to chose an inner product in $V$ in order to calculate its signature, so the signature of $B_{Tr}$ shouldn't depend on the choice of $g$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user1234567890: The signature of $B_g$ is $(n^2,0)$ since $B_g$ is an inner product. However, $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ coincides with $B_g$ on $\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{self}}(V)$ and with $-B_g$ on $\operatorname{End}_{\textrm{skew}}(V)$ and those spaces are $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$-orthogonal so you get the signature of $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$. Regarding your second point, the signature of $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ does not depend on $g$, the inner product $g$ only gives you a nice way to calculate it.

Comment: @user1234567890: You can calculate the signature of $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ "directly" by identifying $\operatorname{End}(V)$ with $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and then verifying that the spaces of skew-symmetric and symmetric matrices are orthogonal and calculate the signature on each of the subspaces. However, the identification of $\operatorname{End}(V)$ with $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ depends on a choice of a basis and this is the same as choosing some basis, declaring it to be orthonormal and working on $\operatorname{End}(V)$ instead of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. You asked for a "coordinate independent" argument

Comment: and I suspect this is the closest thing you'll get (at the price of using an auxiliary inner product).

Comment: You could get a slightly closer version if instead of worrying about orthogonality of the decomposition you just appeal to the coordinate-independent definition "max dimension of (positive/negative)-definite subspace etc" for signature and index.  I suppose we could use an isomorphism $V\to V^*$ instead of necessarily an inner product on $V$ (so allowing eg symplectic).

Comment: 1 - Then read the last sentence just before the line in your answer. It says "...the index of $B_{g}$ is $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\frac{n(n-1)}{2})$", but you wanted to write "...the index of $B_{Tr}$ is $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\frac{n(n-1)}{2})$". Am I right? 2 - Ok. So an inner product is positive definite by definition for you. What happens if you take a non-degenerate non-positive definite one? Don't answer this if you don't want to. It is beyond our objetives.

Comment: About the other two comments, thanks for taking care about the coordinate-free argument. I hope there is a way to do this without a $g$ and in a coordinate-free way, but i'm afraid that it will involve polynomials.

Comment: @user1234567890: Regarding $(1)$, it was a typo. Thanks for catching it up, I've edited my answer. Regarding $(2)$, I never thought about adjoints in the pseudo-Riemannian context but it might work out. The reason I used an inner product is that the signature of $B_g$ becomes trivial and then one can compare $B_g$ to $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$ to calculate the signature of $B_{\operatorname{tr}}$. This is the same idea as checking how $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ behaves on symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices.

Comment: @user1234567890: Also, in part $(2)$ of your question, you write "symmetric and alternating" endomorphisms. Note that if $V$ is just a vector space (without additional structure) there is no meaning to symmetric or alternating endomorphisms. You need an inner product (or, more generally, a non-degenerate pairing) to talk about these notions.

Comment: @levap about your first comment, thanks, I'll think about it. About the second, read my  comment about that in the other answer.

Comment: @user1234567890:  Think about $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. When $A$ is symmetric, all the eigenvalues of $A^T A = A^2$ are non-negative and in particular the sum of the eiganvalues $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)$ is non-negative. However, the condition $\operatorname{tr}(A^2) > 0$ need not imply that all the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are non-negative, only their sum is, so there's no reason to think that $\operatorname{tr}(A^2) \geq 0$ is equivalent to symmetry.

Comment: @levap You are right (I deleted the comment) but it is true that the idea can be used to define the notion of symmetric and skew-symmetric endomorphisms without coordinates and without inner products via this decomposition: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hilbert_space_with_an_indefinite_metric (look for a3 and a4)

Comment: @levap ah [...], the decomposition is not unique so it can't be used to define anything.  Can I conclude now that $End(TM)$ has a natural pseudo-riemannian structure? $TM$ is the tangent bundle of a manifold $M$.

Comment: @user1234567890: I have no idea how the link you attached is relevant since all the spaces there come equipped with some extra structure (such as a "generalized inner product"). In any case, yes, the vector bundle $\operatorname{End}(TM)$ (not the manifold $TM$!) has a natural pseudo-Riemannian metric.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much @levap , I always wanted to find an example where pseudo-riemannian geometry naturally arises unrelated to General Relativity, Lorentzian Geometry and etc. I give you the green check, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Recall real symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues and antisymmetric matrices have purely imaginary eigenvalues.  So what can you say about the sign of $A\mapsto\operatorname{Tr}(A\circ A)=\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)$ for symmetric/antisymmetric $A$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If $A$ is skew-symmetric and non zero, then $A^2$ is symmetric and negative semi-definite, so as the trace is the sum of the elements of the diagonal, $Tr(A^2)<0$. I don't know how to keep going with the symmetric case because I don't know what can be said about the "definitness" of $A^2$ if $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: @user1234567890: If $A$ is symmetric then $A^2 = A^T A$ is positive definite.

Comment: @user1234567890 recall trace is the sum of eigenvalues, and a (diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$ since it is symmetric/antisymmetric) matrix with only $0$ as eigenvalue is the zero matrix.

Comment: @levap Brilliant. Then $Tr(A^2)>0$ if A is symmetric and non-zero, isn't it? This can be done in a coordinate-free way.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks for your work, you gave me the right idea, but I'm not interested in the complex case.

Comment: @user1234567890 we are not really using the complex case, just that antisymmetric matrices are only diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$ since its eigenvalues are purely imaginary.  But then we will promptly square it to forget about anything outside the reals.

Comment: @user10354138 ah, you are right, but anyway it is solved, isn't it? $Tr(A^2)>0$ for non-zero symmetric matrices and $Tr(A^2)<0$ for non-zero skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: @user1234567890 No, you can't define symmetric (resp. skew-symmetric) using just sign of the quadratic form (exercise: sum of two "symmetric" need not be "symmetric" in this definition).